# SQL statement not returning exact results expected

Tags: sql

Let me start out by saying I am not an expert in SQL coding. I thought I had this query down until I put it into SSRS and noticed my 'Consumption' is doubling the value is almost all cases. I can't figure out what is wrong. I have changed the joins but never get expected results. Here is the query.

```
SELECT  a.No_
       ,Sum(b.Consumption) as Consumption
       ,sum(c.[Item Ledger Entry Quantity]) as 'Total Qty'
       ,sum(e.Amount) as 'Total Amount'
FROM Crest$Item a
INNER JOIN (SELECT  [Item No_] INo, Sum(Quantity) Consumption
                     FROM            [Crest$Item Ledger Entry]
                     WHERE        [Entry Type] = 5 and [Posting Date]      Between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-31'
                     GROUP BY [Item No_]) b on a.No_ = b.INo
INNER JOIN [Crest$Value Entry] c ON a.No_ = c.[Item No_] 
INNER JOIN [Crest$G_L - Item Ledger Relation] d on c.[Entry No_] = d.[Value Entry No_]
INNER JOIN [Crest$G_L Entry] e ON d.[G_L Entry No_] = e.[Entry No_]
WHERE e.[G_L Account No_] = '55130'
       and c.[Posting Date] between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-31'
group by a.No_
order by a.No_
```

When the data is returned I have correct data in columns No_, Total Qty, and Total Amount but the second column 'consumption' is more times than not exactly double the value that it is supposed to be.

I am not seeing the issue. 
Thank you.

Comment: Seems that the sum of consuption is multiplied with the rows of the outer query. Either aggregrate also some of the rest tables or use group by on the consumption field on the outer query instead of reusing sum

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server  2014

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the issue will probably become apparent if you remove all the sum(...) functions and just return the raw data and inspect it.

Without the raw data or schema, my best guess is that with all of those that you're getting a condition that you end up returning 2 of "b" based on the joins to "c, "d" or "e". It's the fact you say "more times than not" that makes me think this is what's going on.

Fixing it depends exactly on where the problem lies. It can be really simple sometimes (maybe you need to only get "c" where some column is equal to a specific value), or need step back and look at how it's all structured together.